# how to create multiple switch network using mininet

Tags: networking, command, switch-statement

I used `sudo mn --topo single,12` command to create single switch and 12 hosts in `mininet`.

Now how can I create multiple switch topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `--topo tree,depth=2,fanout=2` for a tree like network, or you can use the python APIs to create a topology as you see fit like so : https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2013-September/002881.html